# How to get containing application version from it's extension on iOS8?

Tags: ios, widget, ios8

I have an app with an extension on iOS8.

In extension, I make calls to my own API server with parameters those include "application version".

- I can keep extension version and app version equal on every application deployment to App Store.
- I can set application version to shared `NSUserDefaults` that can be read by extension.

I don't prefer above solutions. Is there anyway to get the containing application's version dynamically?

Comment: I don't think there is a proper solution. I'll use the 2nd option if I need this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to access infoDictionary? You can reach many information about your app from that.

For current version;

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"current version = %@", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]]
```

Comment: That shows the version of the extension unfortunately.